# Set field's value in Inherited class from base

Tags: c#

I think it is easy, but i don't know how :)

```
class base1
{
    public int x = 1;
//... many other fields
}

class inherit1:base1
{
    int y = 5;
  ...
}
base bs=new base1();
// set many fields value of the bs class
bs.value1=5;
bs.value15="sss";
//....set other fileds values

inherit1 i1=new inherit1();
```

what is the fastest way to set all fields value inherited class i1 equal to base fields value bs?
I want to do something like this:

```
i1=bs;
```

and after init all other field i1.

Thank!

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit more..? Give us an example of what you want to do? It's very very hard to find your goal in this question

Comment: I need to set all fields value inherited class equal base class fields value...

Comment: You want to copy the values from `bs` to `inherit1`?  You don´t need to do this as the constructor of `inherit1` will autoamtically call that one from `base` and therefor will initialize the same values for you.

Comment: no, base class fields value is not equal to initialization value at constructor, it was used early and have fields value other then initialization value in constructor. And i need to set all fields inherited class equal base...

Comment: I think you want to clone -- deep copy -- an object. It's a known issue in C# which can be solved in different ways, none of which is perfect. (C++ has a better approach there, imho.) One of them: You may want to look at `Object.MemberwiseClone()` which simply copies all fields and can be the start of your own `DeepClone()` function. For value fields like Int, float, structs this means you'll receive a true copy -- what else could one do with tem? For reference types it will just copy the reference, which is good enough for immutable types. For mutable types you'll have to deep-copy yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't just assign base class intance to the derived type. You need to convert it.

So, your first choise is to use [`AutoMapper`](http://automapper.org/). It helps you to copy data from object type to other. It will automatically map proprties with the same names. At the end you will use such code f.e:

```
var derived = Mapper.Map<Base, Derived>(b);
```

And the second choice is to write a method and to use reflection.

And use it in the constructor:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived(Base b)  
    {
        SetProperties(b);
    }

    private void SetProperties(object mainClassInstance)
    {
        var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
        var mainClassType = mainClassInstance.GetType();

        MemberInfo[] members = mainClassType.GetFields(bindingFlags).Cast<MemberInfo>()
            .Concat(mainClassType.GetProperties(bindingFlags)).ToArray();

        foreach (var memberInfo in members)
        {
            if (memberInfo.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
            {
                var propertyInfo = memberInfo as PropertyInfo;
                object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(mainClassInstance, null);

                if (null != value)
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(this, value, null);
            }
            else
            {
                var fieldInfo = memberInfo as FieldInfo;
                object value = fieldInfo.GetValue(mainClassInstance);

                if (null != value)
                    fieldInfo.SetValue(this, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just need:

```
Base b = new Base {...};
Derived d = new Derived(b);
```

***Additionally:***

Actually, it will be even better to make `SetProperties` method as extension method.

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static void SetProperties(this object newClassIntance, object mainClassInstance)
    {
        var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
        var mainClassType = mainClassInstance.GetType();

        MemberInfo[] members = mainClassType.GetFields(bindingFlags).Cast<MemberInfo>()
            .Concat(mainClassType.GetProperties(bindingFlags)).ToArray();

        foreach (var memberInfo in members)
        {
            if (memberInfo.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
            {
                var propertyInfo = memberInfo as PropertyInfo;
                object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(mainClassInstance, null);

                if (null != value)
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(newClassIntance, value, null);
            }
            else
            {
                var fieldInfo = memberInfo as FieldInfo;
                object value = fieldInfo.GetValue(mainClassInstance);

                if (null != value)
                    fieldInfo.SetValue(newClassIntance, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And, then you can use this method as: `this.SetInheritedProperties(b);`

Comment: This is right way!  Thank, only in my case FieldInfo (not propertyInfo)

Comment: @ВладимирВ Yep, I didn't paid an attention.

Comment: @ВладимирВ I will update my answer for supporting `FieldInfo` also. Don't forget that you can mark this as the answer.

Comment: @ВладимирВ I have updated my answer. Now, it will support both Property and fields.

Answer (score 0):

You want to copy the values from `bs` to `i1`? You don't need to do this as the constructor of `inherit1` will automatically call that one from `base1` and therefore will initialize the same values for you.

Consider this:

```
class base1
{
    public int x = 1;
    public int y = 1;
}

class inherit1:base1
{
    int z = 5;
  ...
}
base bs=new base1();
// bs now has x = y = 1    

inherit1 i1=new inherit1(); 
// inherit1 also has x = y = 1, and z = 5
```

You can now call `i1.x` which will return `1`.

However if you already have an instance of `base` and want to turn it into an instance of `inherit1` you have to provide some copy-logic, for example as follows:

```
class inherti1 : base1 {
    public inherit1(base1 b) {
        this.x = b.x;
        this.y = b.y;
        this.z = 6;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank.   It is simple, but base class has very many fields, and a i hope,  that exist other way to copy values of the fields, and another thing - base class may change, then i need to change derived class copy-logic....

Comment: The only way around this is using reflection as suggested by Fahrad

Answer (score 0):

In C# assigning a reference to another like `i1=bs;` is actually making the reference i1 refer to the base1 object, which means the inheret1 will be not referenced any more and ready for garbage collection.

The other issue is the `i1=bs;` will cause a syntax error, as you cannot assign a reference to a base class to a reference to a derived class, only the opposite is allowed.

I guess what you are after is cloning.

Make base1 implement the `IClonable` interface and implement the clone method in both base1 and inheret1 classes.

Now instead of using `i1=bs;` for copying objects, use b2 = (base1)b1.Clone(); to copy a base1 object to another.

To be able to copy a base1 object to an inheret1 object, you will need to create a constructor of inheret1 that takes a base1 object and copies all members (or even better an explicit or implicit converter from base1 to inheret1).